# Generating a Word document based on a Web Form

Tags: php, .net, ms-word

I'm writing an application for generating a document out of user pre-filled form.
i.e.:

1. the user fills in a form including some checkbox, radio buttons etc..
2. the relevant text is pulled out from the DB
3. The data should be written into a word document - including some dependencies (automatic numbering,and other designs)
4. The user may preview or download the file

My Question's:

1. which modules should be used in either PHP or ASP.NET code for establishing A Word document? Shell I use HTML/COM/OpenOffice XML?
2. How should the "preview" function be implemented?

Comment: For PHP, there's PHPWord that can be used to generate a Word document (Office Open XML .docx rather than BIFF .doc)

Comment: @Mark http://phpword.codeplex.com/ :) And here is an example for .NET: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/wordapplication.aspx